# python: moving from uwsgi to http-socket

Tags: python, sockets, nginx, uwsgi

I'm using a python app ([modoboa](http://modoboa.org/en/)) which used to be served with uwsgi to nginx via uwsgi-protocol.

I'm trying out [h2o](https://h2o.examp1e.net) server now which doesn't speak the uwsgi protocol but http.

So I'm trying to migrate uwsgi from using a uwsgi-socket to a http-socket, but uwsgi throws an error "no python application found" at the point I am now.

This was in my `nginx.conf`:

```
location /modoboa/ {
        root /usr/local/www/modoboa_default/modoboa_default;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi-modoboa.sock;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT modoboa_default.wsgi:application;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME https;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /modoboa;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    }
```

This was my `uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /usr/local/www/modoboa_default
module = modoboa_default.wsgi:application
master = true
harakiri = 60
processes = 4
vhost = true
no-default-app = true
```

This is my `uwsgi.ini` now:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /usr/local/www/modoboa_default
module = modoboa_default.wsgi:application
master = true
harakiri = 60
processes = 4
vhost = true
no-default-app = true
http-socket=/tmp/uwsgi-http.sock
enable-threads=true
buffer-size=60000
http-keepalive=3000
```

I guess I'm missing something in my uwsgi.ini

---

### update

this is what I have so far

`h2o.conf`

```
        "/modoboa/":
            proxy.reverse.url: "http://[unix:/tmp/uwsgi-http.sock]/"
            proxy.timeout.keepalive: 1000
            proxy.preserve-host: ON

        "/modoboa/sitestatic/":
            file.dir: /usr/local/www/modoboa_default/sitestatic/

        "/modoboa/media/":
            file.dir: /usr/local/www/modoboa_default/media/
```

`uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /usr/local/www/modoboa_default
harakiri = 60
processes = 4
http-socket = /tmp/uwsgi-http.sock
enable-threads = true
mount = /modoboa=modoboa_default.wsgi:application
manage-script-name = true
```

This works for the start page.
However, when I login I will get redirected to `example.com/accounts/login/` instead of `example.com/modoboa/accounts/login/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `vhost` and `no-default-app` options if you're explicitly setting module in uWSGI configuration. With that options set, uWSGI is expecting to get information about that from HTTP server, but H2O is not setting anything.

Also, it is insecure to user that settings with servers that can send proper headers unless you're exactly know what they're for, so remove them also from your existing configuration for nginx. You have `module` set in uWSGI config.

Comment: thanks! I removed both and changed the location in h2o to `http://[unix:/tmp/uwsgi-http.sock]/modoboa/`. Now I still can't get it to run because the script seems to not recognize the subfolder – some resources aren't found.

Comment: I got it to work for the start site but I'm getting a wrong redirect for the app. updated the configs above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have the following in the [uwsgi] section (i.e. the same socket name in uwsgi.ini and nginx.conf)

`socket = /tmp/uwsgi-modoboa.sock`

`chmod-socket = 644`

If 644 doesn't work, try 666 or even 777 (be aware of the security issues with wide open permission on a shared server)